# Using Jubula jars in JavaFX

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, testfx, jubula

I have to develop a program (like squish / jubula / zaptest ) test applications that programmed with JavaFX. So my questions are:

1) Can jubula jars be added to an application as a test framework libraries (like TestFX) ? And if so, is there a documentation or tutorial for this? I tried to use TestFX but got into huge problems with hooking and AUT.

2) Can Jubula be modified as it was a different Eclipse tool? And how?

Every comment will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Jubula has a jar (RC - remote control) for JavaFX. It's launched with the application; this makes the AUT controllable by the Jubula agent. I don't know how hard it is to hook an app with TestFX, in Jubula it's well documented how to do it.

2) However it's open source, setting up the build-chain of an RCP application can be a tremendous amount of work. I recommend you don't change Jubula; when it can't do something you need, then write java methods in your application instead and invoke them with the agent.

To your comment: From 8.0 you can control your AUT agent from Java, but it's rather inconvenient: https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2015/july/article3.php

The test-case editor is way easier to use and it has the same capabilities.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is there a documentation or tutorial for RC? And how to call it from java code? I may abondon TestFX if i can use jubula completely from java code

Comment: I edited the answer. Jubula has a well documented help built in, and you can google Bredex's website for tutorials. They also answer to support questions regulary, regardless of being a non-paying user.

Comment: Thank you for you answer but just to clarify you meant the Jubula program itself as the test-case editor right? If it was up to me i would just use that but my boss tells me to write something like jubula (and i dont have much of an idea how to that :D )
Btw i cant upvote your answer due to my low reputation :(

Comment: Jubula is not only a stand-alone application but an Eclipse feature too, you can extend your Eclipse with it. In this case, you'll need to place the native artifact called autagent on the computer running the AUT and you can connect to it from Eclipse. No need to write/fork your own Jubula.